# Div white space inbetween, how do I remove?

Tags: html, css

I need to remove the white space in-between the two sections, I have already tried to use negative margins but that messes up more of the website. Code pen is listed below to see what it looks like. Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help! Please help!
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLXaVB

No negative margins

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Maxwell Tan | Front-End Developer</title>

    <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>




  </head>
  <body>

    <section id="header">
             <header class="site-header">
                 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
                     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="border:none;background-color: rgba(65,95,166);">
                         <div class="container">
                             <div class="navbar-header" style="">
                                  <button class="navbar-toggle"  data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                             </div>
                            <a href="index.html" style="font-family: Lato; font-weight: 300;float: left;font-weight: 300; font-size: 140%; color: white; position:absolute;left:15%;top:10px;  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px">Maxwell Tan</a>
                             <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="">
                                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                   <li><a class="zoominxs" href="#head" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 120%; color: white;  font-family: Lato;">Home</a></li>
                                   <li><a class="zoominxs" href="#about" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 120%; color: white; font-family: Lato;">About</a></li>
                                   <li><a class="zoominxs" href="#offer" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 120%; color: white; font-family: Lato;">Offers</a></li>
                                   <li><a class="zoominxs" href="#dev" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 120%; color: white; font-family: Lato;">Development & Design</a></li>
                                   <li><a class="zoominxs" href="#contact" style="font-weight: 300; font-size: 120%; color: white; font-family: Lato;">Contact</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </header>
           </section>


               <header id="head">
                 <h1 class="animated rubberBand" style="font-size: 350%; padding-top: 300px; font-family: Fira Sans; padding-left: 15%;">The Key to becoming the next Successful Business.</h1><h2 style="padding-top: 30px; font-size: 200%; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 15%; font-family: Lato; font-weight: 300;">A Stunning Website.</h2>
                 <a href="#about" style="transition-duration: 2s;"><button class="button" id="learnmore" style="margin-left: 15%;"><span style="font-weight: 600; font-family: Lato;">Learn More</span></button></a>
                 <h1 style="margin-top: 100px;"></h1>
               </header>

    <section id="about" style="background-color: #415FA6; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <h1 class="title"style="font-size: 300%; margin-bottom: 0;font-family: Lato; text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: 600; font-family: Fira Sans; padding-top: 50px;">HMM.. DON'T YOU WANT TO <br>GET TO KNOW ME FIRST?</h1>
        <center><img id="logo" style="padding-top: 50px;" alt="Maxy" width="250" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" src="img/logo.png"></img></center>
        <p style="text-align: center; color: white; padding-top: 50px; font-size: 130%; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 100;">Hey there, I am Maxwell Tan my online alias being Maxey.<br>I am a 14 year old and have been studying Front-End Website Development for 4 years.</p>
        <p style="text-align: center; color: white; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 130%; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 100;">Outside of Website Development, <br>I enjoy playing Fortnite, doing Martial Arts, and streaming on Twitch.</p>
        <center><a href="https://twitch.tv/maxystreams" style="transition-duration: 2s;"><button class="button" id="twitch"><span style="font-weight: 600; font-family: Lato;">Check out my Twitch Channel</span></button></a></center>
        <h3 style="padding-bottom: 30px;"></h3>
    </section>


    <section id="offer" style="  margin-top: -30px; padding-bottom: 100px;">
      <h1 class="title" style="font-size: 300%; padding-top: 100px; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 600; color: #415FA6; text-align: center; ">WHAT CAN I OFFER?</h1>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 80px; margin-bottom: 50px"><img  class="zoominsmall" src="img/design.png" height="120" width="120"><h3 style="font-weight: 200; font-family: Fira Sans;">Sleek Design</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 80px; margin-bottom: 50px"><img class="zoominsmall" src="img/html.png" height="120" width="120"><h3 style="font-weight: 200; font-family: Fira Sans;">Clean Code</h3></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-top: 80px; margin-bottom: 50px"><img class="zoominsmall" src="img/satisfaction.png" height="120" width="120"><h3 style="font-weight: 200; font-family: Fira Sans;">Customer Satisfaction</h3></div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <section id="dev" style=" margin-top: 200px;background-color: #415FA6;">
      <h1 class="title" style="font-size: 300%; padding-top: 100px; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 600; color: white; text-align: center;">WEBSITE DEVELOPMENT & DESIGN</h1>
      <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 50px;color: white; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 100; font-size: 150%; padding-bottom: 10px;">Having trouble growing a business you know has <b>potential</b>? <br>This is what I am here for. I offer <b>Professional</b> Website Development and a <b>Stunning Design</b> to <b>attract</b> many clients towards your business. <br>What are you waiting for?</P>
      <center><a href="#contact" style="transition-duration: 2s;"><button class="button" id="twitch"><span style="font-weight: 600; font-family: Lato;">Get a Free Quote</span></button></a></center>
      <h1 style="padding-bottom: 50px;"></h1>
      </section>


    <section id="contact">


          <h1 class="title" style="font-size: 300%; padding-top: 100px; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 600; color: #415FA6; text-align: center; margin: 0;">Let's get in touch, I'm always up for a conversation!</h1>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="col-md-4" onclick="alert('Hey there! Feel free to contact me on Discord @ Maxy#4414.');" style="margin-top: 100px;  padding-bottom: 120px;"><img src="img/discord.png" class="zoominsmall" style=" height: 80px;"></img><h3 style="font-family: Fira Sans;color: black; font-weight: 300;">Discord</h3></div>
          <a href="mailto:max@mwstan.com"><div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 100px;  padding-bottom: 120px;"><img class="zoominsmall" src="img/email.png" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;"></img><h3 style="font-family: Fira Sans;color: black; font-weight: 300;">E-mail</h3></div></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/maxtan18"><div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 100px;  padding-bottom: 120px;"><img class="zoominsmall" src="img/instagram.png" style="height: 80px; width: 80px;"></img><h3 style="font-family: Fira Sans;color: black; font-weight: 300;">Instagram</h3></div></a>
        </div>

        <h1 style="color: black; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 400; font-size: 130%; text-align: center; padding-top: 100px;">Copyright © 2018 Maxwell Tan. All Rights Reserved.</h1>
        <h2 style="color: black; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Fira Sans; font-weight: 400; font-size: 130%; text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; ">Website designed by Maxwell Tan</h2>
        </section>



        <center><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    TrustLogo("http://mwstan.com/img/comodo.png", "CL1", "none");
    </script></center>

    </body>




</html>
```

Comment: Which 2 sections? You have 5 sections.

Comment: Hey Maxy, looks like you're new here. It's a good idea to cut down the amount of embedded code you have to the minimum that still displays all the relevant information - e.g. in this case removing all of the `<head>` and only displaying the important pieces of the `body`. Also - please don't spam **Please help!**, that won't make anyone *more* inclined to help

Comment: I am talking about the first section and the second section

Comment: I also can't understand what do you want to happen. please explain clearly.
you can show us the picture of what do you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your styles are getting overwritten, and bootstrap is adding a `margin-top: 20px` to your `h1` element in the section below your hero

[image]

[image: margin-top 20px]

Add this to your css

```
h1.title {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: So how would I fix it?

Comment: you can add a `margin-top: 0` to your header element. I will update my answer